# Ошибка Fragment does not have a view по нажатию кнопки

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager, android-dialog

Есть `Fragment` содержащий кнопку, по нажатию на которую вызывается `DialogFragment`. Он в свою очередь содержит два фрагмента и требуется реализовать `ViewPager` позволяющий перелистывать эти два фрагмента в диалоге.
После нажатия на кнопку, возвращается ошибка в дебаг режиме

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view
```

Полный стек трейс:

```
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent, PID: 12467
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment$1.onFindViewById(Fragment.java:2181)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:963)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:562)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:149)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-29 22:56:31.469 12467-12467/com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Собственно сами классы 
1) DialogFragment

```
package com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateAndTimePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String EXTRA_DATE = "com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent.date";
    public static final int NUM_ITEMS = 2;

    private ViewPager mViewPageFragment;
    private Date mDate;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDate = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_DATE);

        mViewPageFragment = new ViewPager(getActivity());
        mViewPageFragment.setId(R.id.viewPagerInFragment);

        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        mViewPageFragment.setAdapter(new MyDateManager(fm));

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                    .setView(mViewPageFragment)
                                    .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
                                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .create();
    }

    private void sendResult(int resultCode) {
        if (getTargetFragment() == null)
            return;
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, mDate);

        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, i);
    }

    public static DateAndTimePickerDialogFragment newInstance(Date date) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_DATE, date);
        DateAndTimePickerDialogFragment fragment = new DateAndTimePickerDialogFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    class MyDateManager extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyDateManager(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(mDate);
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            Log.d(CrimeListFragment.TAG, "get item num = " + position);
            switch (position) {
                case 0:

                    return DatePickFragment.newInstance(year, month, day);
                case 1:
                    return TimePickFragment.newInstance(hour, minute);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }
    }
}
```

2) Fragment содержащийся в DialogFragment

```
package com.rmr.ngusarov.criminalintent;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class DatePickFragment extends Fragment{
    public static final String DATE_YEAR_KEY = "date_year";
    public static final String DATE_MONTH_KEY = "date_month";
    public static final String DATE_DAY_KEY = "date_day";

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private Date mDate;
    public View datePick;
    public DatePicker mDatePicker;

    public static DatePickFragment newInstance(int year, int month, int day) {
        DatePickFragment datePickFragment = new DatePickFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DATE_YEAR_KEY, year);
        args.putInt(DATE_MONTH_KEY, month);
        args.putInt(DATE_DAY_KEY, day);
        datePickFragment.setArguments(args);
        Log.d(CrimeListFragment.TAG, "new instance for new DP = OK!");
        return datePickFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(CrimeListFragment.TAG, "onCreate start DP = OK!");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        year = getArguments().getInt(DATE_YEAR_KEY);
        month = getArguments().getInt(DATE_MONTH_KEY);
        day = getArguments().getInt(DATE_DAY_KEY);
        Log.d(CrimeListFragment.TAG, "onCreate DP = OK! day = " + day);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(CrimeListFragment.TAG, "before init view  DP = OK!");
        mDatePicker = (DatePicker) datePick.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_datePiker);
        datePick = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);

        Log.d(CrimeListFragment.TAG, "after init view  DP = OK!");

        Log.d(CrimeListFragment.TAG, "before init DP = OK!");
        mDatePicker.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth).getTime();
                getArguments().putSerializable(DateAndTimePickerDialogFragment.EXTRA_DATE, mDate);
            }
        });
        Log.d(CrimeListFragment.TAG, "after init DP = OK!");

        return datePick;
    }
}
```

3) Класс второго фрагмента аналогичен предыдущему по сему не вижу смысла выкладывать.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема или какой информации стоит добавить для увеличения вероятности помощи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Измени местами строки с:

```
mDatePicker = (DatePicker)datePick.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_datePiker);
datePick = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);
```

на :

```
datePick = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);
mDatePicker = (DatePicker)datePick.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_datePiker);
```

Comment: Да, я уже менял местами эти вызовы, и у меня в примере который я выложил не корректная последовательность. Пробовал в т.ч. getActivity().getLayoutInflater(). Но причина не в этом - стектрейс не изменился, то есть до этого момента выполнение не доходит, судя по всему

Answer (score 3):

Здесь вся беда состоит в том, что, когда создаётся дочерний `FragmentManager`, ему обязательно нужно, чтобы у родительского фрагмента был вид. А поскольку `DateAndTimePickerDialogFragment` использует `onCreateDialog`, никакого вида в `onCreateView` он не создаёт, и в итоге и получается проблема.

Решения тут я вижу два: можно либо создавать диалог через `onCreateView`, либо реализовать `PagerAdapter` вручную и не использовать фрагменты внутри диалога. Лично мне второй вариант кажется более предпочтительным, потому что в первом придётся все кнопки и стили делать самостоятельно, что довольно непросто.